# How many 3-element subsets are there of set ${1,2,...5n}$ in which number 2 appears?

Tags: probability

$\binom{3}{5n}$

This is how I would do it if it weren't for the last part (number 2 must appear).

How can I include it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an obvious bijection between three-element subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots,5n\}$ which contain $2$ and two-element subsets of $\{1,3,4,5,\dots,5n\}$.  No need to break into cases or anything like that.

The answer is $$\binom{5n-1}{2}$$

Comment: Can I apply it to similar tasks?
For example if it was "How many 3-element subsets are there of set ${1,2,...2n}$ in which number 1 appears?"=
$\binom{2n-1}{2}$

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: How would it change if it was 'doesn't contain number 2? $\binom{2n-1}{3}$?

Comment: Yes, of course.  If you further continue to look for generalizations, you will quickly run into compound statements such as "does contain $1$ and does not contain $2$" in which case you just do both.  Depending on the statement, [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) may also come into play, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Thank you, I finally understand this task and I am confident I will get it right on exam

Answer (score 2):

In your question I think you mean ${5n}\choose{3}$ instead of the other way round.

For every 3 element subset of $\{1,2,\ldots, 5n\}$ with $2$ in it think about the same subset without the $2$. For example
$$
\{2, 1, 3\}\rightarrow \{1,3\}\ \\
\{2, 4, 7\}\rightarrow \{4,7\} \\
\{2, 1, 5\} \rightarrow \{1,5\} 
$$
This is a one-to-one correspondence between the subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots, 5n\}$ of size 3 and the subsets of $\{1,3,4,\ldots, 5n\}$ of size two.

The size of the latter family is ${5n-1}\choose{2}$, so this is you answer, namely:
$$
{{5n-1}\choose{2}} = \frac{(5n-1)(5n-2)}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the subsets are not ordered, i.e $\{1,2,3\} = \{3,1,2\}$.

So a 3-element subset of $\{1,2,...,5n\}$ is of the form
$$  \{x,y,z\} \mbox{ where } x<y<z \mbox{ and } x,y,z \in \{ 1,2, ... , 5n \} $$
and we will count how many of these exist and contain $2$.

Note that $z$ cannot be $2$, so $0$ ways to do so. If $y=2$ then $x=1$, so there are $$ 5n-2 $$ choices for $z$. If $x=2$, then we have to choose two numbers from $\{ 3,4,...,5n\}$ for $y$ and $z$, $$ {5n-2 \choose 2} $$ ways to do so. Total number of ways
$$ \#ways=0+(5n-2)+ {5n-2 \choose 2} = \frac{(5n-2)(5n-1)}{2} $$

Comment: $\frac{(5n)!}{(6(5n-3)!)} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$
This looks too ugly to be actuall answer... :P

Comment: Definitely not too ugly, BUT my original answer is definitely wrong I will create a new one..

Comment: Ok corrected my answer

Comment: Why did you bother breaking into cases based on which of $x,y,z$ was $2$... Just say that *one of them but it doesn't matter which* was $2$ and the remaining two are selected from the remaining $5n-1$ elements for a total of $\binom{5n-1}{2}$.  Note that $\binom{5n-1}{2}=(5n-2)+\binom{5n-2}{2}$, seen by $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}$

Comment: Even better you can include that as an answer. But when writing my answer, this is the problem solving process I personally went through

Comment: @NazimJ is $\binom{5n-2}{2}$ correct? 2 other answers have is $\binom{5n-1}{2}$.

Comment: This answer is *also* $\binom{5n-1}{2}$ just written differently.